# Qual o primeiro dia da semana para o Brasil?

Tags: gramática

Na área em que eu trabalho, comecei a ver muitos calendários e dias da semanas, e repetidas vezes eu vi a segunda-feira sendo tratada como primeiro dia da semana. Fiquei em dúvida e resolvi pesquisar a respeito. Pra minha surpresa, vi que muitos lugares/institutos definem segunda, como realmente sendo o primeiro dia.
Mas, oficialmente no Brasil, é domingo ou segunda?

Referências:

- https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/afinal-domingo-e-o-comeco-ou-o-fim-da-semana/
- https://www.calendarr.com/brasil/qual-o-primeiro-dia-da-semana/

Comment: Tecnicamente, a pergunta é sobre cultura e não sobre língua. Mas acho-a uma muito boa pergunta para ter por cá, muito útil!

Comment: Obrigado. Tive que perguntar aqui, pois eu realmente não achei outro lugar que fosse mais adequado para realizar essa pergunta.

Comment: Né só no Brasil, não.....

Comment: O problema pode estar na definição, talvez esteja referindo ao dia útil. Nos calendários impressos mostram domingo como primeiro dia, tinha sempre vários em casa, mas usamos o termo fim de semana (sábado e domingo). Com essa mistura de termos, conceito de "dia útil" foi sempre foi uma grande confusão na minha cabeça desde criança (felizmente resolvido). Afinal, como segunda pode ser primeiro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a norma [NBR 5892:2019](https://www.normas.com.br/visualizar/abnt-nbr-nm/5296/abnt-nbr5892-informacao-e-documentacao-representacao-e-formatos-de-tempo-datas-e-horas-apresentacao) ([e-print](https://www.scribd.com/document/476670229/NBR-5892-2019-Informacao-e-Documentacao-Representacao-e-Formatos-de-Tempo-Datas-e-Horas-Apresentacao)) da Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas (ABNT), o primeiro dia da semana é o domingo:

> **2.2. Dias da semana**
> A semana é divida em sete dias, iniciando-se no domingo e terminando no sábado.

que corresponde à convenção [chamada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Schematic_representation_of_ISO_week_date) de "tradicional ocidental" (*Western traditional*).

Mas é muito comum utilizar-se "semana" se referindo implicitamente à "semana útil", que se inicia na segunda-feira - que é também a convenção internacional estabelecida no [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 2):

De forma bem direta, oficialmente o primeiro dia da semana é o domingo mesmo, mas comercialmente consideramos a segunda-feira.

> A segunda-feira é o 1° dia útil **considerado o segundo dia da semana**, seguindo o domingo e precedendo a terça-feira.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segunda-feira

Comment: O artigo da Wikipedia mencionado não cita nenhuma fonte original para embasar esta afirmação.

Answer (score 1):

No geral, a semana realmente se inicia no domingo e termina no sábado. Mas como o domingo se trata de um dia "inútil" comercialmente, os brasileiros costumam afirmar que o primeiro dia da semana é a segunda, e o último, o domingo.

Comment: Olá Bruna, bem vida ao site. Você escreveu "se inicia no domingo e termina na segunda", mas quis dizer "se inicia no domingo e termina no sábado", não? Fiz a alteração para você. Um segundo ponto: se espera que as respostas aqui, dentro do possível, contenham referências, de modo que se possa saber que elas têm um embasamento além da mera opinião de quem posta.

Answer (score -1):

No Brasil acreditamos que o primeiro dia da semana comesse PELA SEGUNDA FEIRA por ser o primeiro DIA útil  da semana,e O DIA de domingo é  o último dia da semana, por fazer parte do CHAMADO FINAL DE SEMANA, E NÃO SER UM DIA ÚTIL também.

Comment: Bem vindo ao site! Aqui existem ferramentas de formatação dentro da plataforma para evitar o uso de caixa alta nos textos e geralmente colocamos referências para melhorar a qualidade das respostas, aumentar a confiabilidade e evitar que a resposta se resuma em opinião pessoal.